# How can I plot a result of Laplace Transform?

Tags: plotting, complex

Is it possible to [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) the output of [`LaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html) with Mathematica?

Obviously when I apply `LaplaceTransform` to a function I obtain a function of parameter `s`... but is implicit defined as `sigma+j*omega`, but I can't see this....(like the following example shown).

```
LaplaceTransform[Sin[t], t, s]
```

> ```
> 1/(1 + s^2)
> ```

Can I plot this function?
Can I plot the `Abs[]` of the Laplace transformed function?

I wish obtain a graphic like this

[image]

Thx :)

Comment: @Artes I don't see the Re+Im part, because appear only parameter " s " , so i think that my question isn't a duplicate

Comment: `Plot3D[Abs[1/(1 + s^2) /. s -> x + I y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}]`

Comment: @Artes thx, now it's clear :D

Answer (score 3):

The answer is YES, it is possible to Plot the output of [`LaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html) with *Mathematica*.

To understand how to plot functions in general read the documentation for [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html).

```
Plot[
 1/(1 + s^2)
 , {s, -4, 4}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Your would get the same if you use

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@LaplaceTransform[Sin[t], t, s]
 , {s, -4, 4}
 ]
```

or if you assign a new function name to the the transformed function

```
out[s_] = LaplaceTransform[Sin[t], t, s]

Plot[
 out[s]
 , {s, -4, 4}
 ]
```

For complex `s` you could use

```
Plot3D[
 Abs[1/(1 + Complex[x, y]^2)]
 , {x, -1, 1}
 , {y, -1, 1}
 , MaxRecursion -> 5
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
Plot3D[
 Evaluate@ReIm[1/(1 + Complex[x, y]^2)]
 , {x, -1, 1}
 , {y, 0, 2}
 , MaxRecursion -> 5
 , PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Red, Opacity[0.3]]
   , Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.3]]
   }
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]